# How does the "Carlisle method" work? (used to detect improper randomization in studies)

Tags: references, anomaly-detection, clinical-trials, random-allocation

The NPR news article [Errors Trigger Retraction Of Study On Mediterranean Diet's Heart Benefits](https://www.npr.org/sections/health-shots/2018/06/13/619619302/errors-trigger-retraction-of-study-on-mediterranean-diets-heart-benefits) refers to something it calls the "Carlisle method" of analyzing results of published studies to look for signs that subjects of the studies were not properly randomized.

**Question:** If possible, I'd like to get a basic understanding of the method that Carlisle used to detect improper randomization in studies.

> Carlisle [found the odds were infinitesimally small](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1365-2044.2012.07128.x) that Fujii had randomized people properly. Since Carlisle's findings were published in 2012, medical journals have retracted [more than 160 papers by Fujii](http://retractiondatabase.org/RetractionSearch.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1#?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport%3d1%26auth%3dFujii%252c%2bYoshitaka) — the most retractions for any one researcher, by a large margin, according to Retraction Watch.
>
> Carlisle's analysis drew accolades — and added him to the [ranks of a small but growing number of such sleuths](https://twitter.com/RetractionWatch/status/1006534415693082624). The success of the approach prompted Carlisle to expand his scope to include randomized trials from other researchers and in other fields.
>
> After the Fujii paper, he spent two years applying the "Carlisle method" to thousands of clinical trials published in eight journals. In 2017, he [reported](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/anae.13938) that roughly [2 percent showed signs of problems](https://retractionwatch.com/2017/06/05/two-100-clinical-trials-eight-major-journals-likely-contain-inaccurate-data-study/).
>
> Among the more than 5,000 trials Carlisle analyzed, 934 were published by the New England Journal of Medicine. He flagged 11. One was the 2013 study showing the Mediterranean diet was responsible for the reduced rates of heart attack and stroke.

Comment: This is my first question here, I may need some help with proper tags.

Comment: (+1) As you type in a tag, a menu of options with brief explanations should pop up.  Trial-and-error based on what you think the keywords ought to be is usually the best approach--but please read those explanations to make sure you're not misled about the tag's meaning.  It looks like you did pretty well in your choices.

Comment: @whuber thanks! Oh I've used SE before, it's just that I'm new to this particular site and don't have much of a background in this field. It looks like you have literally hundreds and hundreds of tags, so it's better to let someone familliar help me out.

Answer (score 2):

The "Carlisle method" is a statistical technique created by Dr. John Carlisle for determining the likelihood that volunteers in a study were appropriately randomised. This method received significant attention for detecting anomalies in clinical trials, leading to the retraction of several papers due to randomisation difficulties.

**Carlisle Method Fundamentals**

The method entails comparing the reported distribution of baseline parameters (such as age, weight, gender, and so on) of participants in different groups of a randomised study with the expected distribution under proper randomisation. Here's a quick rundown of how it works:

1. Carlisle collected data on baseline parameters given in the study, such as the averages and standard deviations of continuous variables (e.g., age, weight) and proportions for categorical variables (e.g., gender, smoker/non-smoker) for each trial group.
2. Statistical Analysis

- Under the premise of proper randomization, he estimated the predicted distribution of these traits. In theory, proper randomization should provide equal distributions of these traits across all groups in the study.
- He then utilised statistical tests to compare the observed and anticipated distributions (such as chi-square tests for categorical variables and t-tests for continuous variables).
- He investigated whether the overall pattern was consistent with what would be expected under good randomisation by aggregating these comparisons across several baseline attributes.
- Extremely low probability suggested that the randomisation method was not carried out properly, raising concerns about the study's findings' validity.

**3. Impact**

- The Importance of Detecting Irregularities: This method has proved helpful in finding anomalies in clinical trial randomisation, which is critical because randomisation is vital to the validity of trial results.
- Carlisle's study resulted in the retraction of many papers, most notably those by researcher Yoshitaka Fujii, who had manipulated data in numerous investigations.

**Limitations:**

**Not Absolute Proof:** While the approach can identify possible flaws with randomisation, it is not conclusive proof of wrongdoing. Other variables could also explain odd baseline characteristic distributions.

**Further research:** Carlisle method findings often necessitate additional research, such as checking trial procedures, data gathering methodologies, and other documentation.

In summary, the Carlisle technique is a statistical strategy for determining the likelihood that a clinical trial's randomisation process was carried out correctly. It compares observed baseline distributions in research groups to those expected under appropriate randomisation, assisting in the identification of trials where randomisation anomalies may have occurred.